# How to hide post meta

Tags: custom-field

I have disqus installed in my website. It adds `dsq_thread_id` meta. And while showing the post meta in post with tag;

```
<?php the_meta(); ?>
```

I want to hide `dsq_thread_id` in all posts.

How can I do this?

Comment: Where do you want to hide it? Is it displayed in admin area or in front-end? In which part of admin area is it displayed? Do you want to hide all post meta fields in this view or only this one?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to hide it in Post. I want to hide this and show other custom field data.

Comment: What do you mean by "in Post"? On post editor page or in front-end?

Comment: I am using this `<?php the_meta(); ?>` to show the custom fields data and i want to exclude dsq_thread_id in post page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, just don't use `the_meta` function and display these fields with your custom code. You can use something like this:

```
function my_filtered_meta($disabled_metas =array()) {
    if ( $keys = get_post_custom_keys() ) {
            echo "<ul class='post-meta'>\n";
            foreach ( (array) $keys as $key ) {
                    $keyt = trim($key);
                    if ( is_protected_meta( $keyt, 'post' ) || in_array($keyt, $disabled_metas ) )
                            continue;
                    $values = array_map('trim', get_post_custom_values($key));
                    $value = implode($values,', ');
                    echo apply_filters('the_meta_key', "<li><span class='post-meta-key'>$key:</span> $value</li>\n", $key, $value);
            }
            echo "</ul>\n";
    }
}
```

And then replace `the_meta` in your theme files with this function call: `my_filtered_meta( array('dsq_thread_id') )`

Another way to do this would be using `is_protected_meta` filter. Just add your own filter to that hook and make this `dsq_thread_id` field protected.

Comment: Where to use this either in functions.php or use it to show meta directly.

Comment: Replace `<?php the_meta(); ?>` in your template with this code. You can add it as function in `functions.php` and then use it in your templates.

Comment: Edited my answer - it should be easier to use now.

Comment: what is the variable keyt means in the function.

Comment: It's trimmed meta_key.